# Putting two corners above a letter like $^{\ulcorner}f^\urcorner$

Tags: spacing, superscripts, left-superscripts

Is there a way to produce something like this `$^{\ulcorner}f^\urcorner$`, thus a symbol f with two corners on top, but elegantly and without the bad spacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different characters seem to need different kerning for the opening “square quote”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\squarequotes}[2][0]{{%
  {\vphantom{#2}}^{\ulcorner}\kern-\scriptspace
  \mspace{-#1mu}%
  {{}#2}^{\urcorner}%
}}

\begin{document}

$\ulcorner f\urcorner$

$\squarequotes{f}$
$\squarequotes[4]{f}$
$\squarequotes{a}$
$\squarequotes[2]{d}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are three solutions with the `\prescript` command from `mathtools`, or using the dedicated packages, `leftidx` and `fouridx`. In all cases one has to add some negative math kerning for the left exponent, due to the italic angle of the maths letters font.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{leftidx, fouridx} 

\begin{document}

\[\prescript{\ulcorner\mkern-9mu}{}{f}^{\urcorner}\quad \fourIdx{\ulcorner\mkern-9mu}{}{\urcorner}{}{f}\quad \leftidx{^{\ulcorner\mkern-9mu}}{f}{^\urcorner}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]